# Integrated Sametime Contact List not visible on the sidebar in Lotus Notes 8.5

Tags: lotus-notes, lotus-sametime

After killing the notes using Kill Notes Utility, I restarted the Lotus Notes. However, I do not see the Sametime Contact List on the sidebar. Can you please help to make it visible again? I am trying to figure out the settings in Preferences without any luck so far.

Comment: Has SameTime ever worked in Notes?

Comment: Yes. I never use SameTime standalone. Have always been using Integrated ST.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make sure that Sametime Contacts is set to be shown in the sidebar using View - Right Sidebar Panels - Sametime Contacts.

[image]